# showing and hiding elements in select with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm attempting to show and hide divs in a select drop down based on their value="".

Could someone explain to me as to why this isn't working? Here is the Jfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/JNyce/11/

```
$('.section_container').children().hide();
$('#form_selection').change(function() {


  var selection = $(this).parent().find("option:selected").text();

    var newselection = selection.split(' ').join('_');

    $('.section_container'+newselection).show();

    });
```

### html

```
<div class="box" style="border: 1px solid black; margin-top:100px;">
<select id="form_selection">
<option value="Program 1">Program 1</option>
<option value="Program 1">Program 2</option>
</select>

        <div class="section_container">
            <div class="Program_1" style="height:200px; border:1px solid black"> 
            <div class="title">Testing</div>
            <span> orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing</span>
            <div class="section_logo" style="width:100px; height:100px; float:left;"><img src="http://www.dublin.k12.ca.us/cms/lib5/CA01001424/Centricity/Domain/35/homeschool.jpg"> </div><button class="blue-pill" style="float:right;">Select Program</button>
            </div>

            <div class="Program_2" style="height:200px; border:1px solid black"> 
            <div class="title">Testing</div>
            <span>orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing </span>
            <div class="section_logo" style="width:100px; height:100px; float:left;"><img src="http://www.dublin.k12.ca.us/cms/lib5/CA01001424/Centricity/Domain/35/homeschool.jpg"> </div>
             <button class="blue-pill" style="float:right;">Select Program</button>
            </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you have `value="Program 1"` twice:

```
<option value="Program 1">Program 1</option>
<option value="Program 1">Program 2</option>
```

This should be:

```
<option value="Program 1">Program 1</option>
<option value="Program 2">Program 2</option>
```

Secondly, you are not selecting the class correctly:

```
$('.section_container' + newselection).show();
```

This should be:

```
$('.section_container .' + newselection).show();
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JNyce/17/)**

**Javascript**

```
$('.section_container > div').hide();
$('#form_selection').change(function () {

    var selection = $(this).val();
    var newselection = selection.replace(' ', '_');

    $('.section_container > div').hide();
    $('.section_container .' + newselection).show();

});
```

Comment: Thanks for that keep forgetting .'s everywhere :P

Answer (score 1):

Here's the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vonDy2791/JNyce/13/)**

```
$('.section_container').children().hide();
$('#form_selection').change(function () {


    var selection = $(this).parent().find("option:selected").text();

    var newselection = selection.split(' ').join('_');
    console.log(newselection);

    $('.section_container').children().hide();
    $('.section_container').find('.' + newselection).show();
});
```